# When using "silhouette coefficient" to evaluate an unsupervised model, do we need a labelled dataset?

Tags: unsupervised-learning

How does "silhouette coefficient" can find the optimal number of clusters when the dataset is not labelled? Does it need a labelled dataset or is it pure statistics?

I mean, when doing unsupervised learning, sometimes, it is used a labelled dataset to verify that the model is doing well. So, I would like to know if "silhouette coefficient" works by using a labelled dataset (even though we do not give it to the algorithm).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find a definition of the [Silhouette coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) on Wikipedia. I won't rehash the definition (let me know if you'd like that anyway), but from this, we see that the silhouette coefficient depends solely on the outputted clusters from any clustering algorithm, *such that there is no need for a labeled dataset.*

Of course, if you had a labeled dataset on hand, you could simply compute classification accuracy, F-score, or whatever classification metric you like directly, where each cluster corresponds to a predicted class. In such cases, I can't think off the top of my head why you'd use a fully unsupervised approach over a supervised one.